# nginx route to cloudfront (to S3)

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to server static site through Cloudfront (and S3). I have S3 bucket `my-bucket` enabled with Static website hosting. NGINX route the traffic based on path. location `/`, `/beta/`, `/static/app/` goes to cloudfront, So I have created **Origins Domain Name and Path** & **Origins ID** for

my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/beta = S3-my-bucket/beta
my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/admin = S3-my-bucket/admin
my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com = S3-my-bucket

And mapped behaviour to
/beta -> S3-my-bucket/beta
/admin -> S3-my-bucket/admin
Default (*) -> S3-my-bucket

I have following Nginx configuration

```
server {
    listen         80 default_server;
    server_name    localhost;
    keepalive_timeout 70;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    location / {
         proxy_pass http://XXXXXX.cloudfront.net;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location /beta/ {
        proxy_pass http://XXXXXX.cloudfront.net/beta/;
    }

    location /static/app/ {
        rewrite ^/static/app/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://XXXXXX.cloudfront.net;
    }
}
```

When I try to open my URL which is pointing to this Nginx I get

```
403 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
Bad request. 
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: 3yYfFbg1ObQ4B-3oco1HYWK46CWh7E8XZOBVl_sdQ6rKMZ4JYZ_KeQ==
```

But if I point Nginx config to my bucket url `proxy_pass http://my-bucket.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com` like this

```
server {
    listen         80 default_server;
    server_name    localhost;
    keepalive_timeout 70;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    location / {
         proxy_pass http://my-bucket.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/;
    }

    location /beta/ {
        proxy_pass http://my-bucket.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/beta/;
    }

    location /static/app/ {
        rewrite ^/static/app/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://my-bucket.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com;
    }
}
```

everything works as expected.

What I need to change to make it work through cloudfront ?

Comment: Removing `proxy_set_header Host $host;` will probably fix the error, so please confirm that... but there's a bigger problem with your setup... Nginx → CloudFront → S3 doesn't make sense to me in this application unless the reason you are using CloudFront is because the bucket is in a different AWS region than Nginx, and even then the justification is pretty soft.  What is the reason you are doing it this way?

Comment: CloudFront only for caching, no other reason. Without `proxy_set_header Host $host;` main URL changes to cloudfront url.

Comment: You have `proxy_pass http://` but have CloudFront set to redirect HTTP to HTTPS.  Change to `proxy_pass https://...` or configure CloudFront with Viewer Protocol Policy: HTTP and HTTPS in each Cache Behavior.

Comment: CloudFront isn't doing any meaningful caching for you in this setup.  With DNS → Nginx → CloudFront → S3, every request is still served through your Nginx server and CloudFront is not caching content near the *browsers* -- it's only caching content near the Nginx server, which is presumably near the bucket anyway, so nothing is gained.  The setup you probably want is DNS → CloudFront → { Nginx or S3 } where the CloudFront Cache Behavior matches paths for the buckets and for the Nginx server and selects the target. This way CloudFront can cache near the viewer, which always contacts it *first*.

Comment: I imagine there is a benefit in doing it this way if the S3 bucket needs to remain private? So fronting it with Cloudfront might be an option.